# get d3.extent of property from a shapefile to use as domain

Tags: json, d3.js

I have a geojson file and am generating a map with D3. I'm creating a choropleth, and using a property in the json file to color the areas of the map. For the color scale, I'm using `d3.scale.quantile()`. If I set the domain manually, it works fine. However, I'm trying to pull the extent of the property in my json file to use as the domain, and am getting NaN instead of values. The property is called "someno".

Here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PmLnKj4BCu2Qi9Y1NOsm?p=preview) that shows what I tried. 
Code is below, too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style>
    #boroughs {
      stroke: none;
        stroke-width: 0px;
        fill: #ddd;
        opacity:.7;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
    }
    #legendcontainer{
      position: absolute;
      bottom:10px;
      right:10px;
    }
    </style>

    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v0.min.js"></script>

    <body>
    <div id="legendcontainer"></div>
    <script>

    var width = Math.max(960, window.innerWidth),
        height = Math.max(500, window.innerHeight);

    var container = d3.select("body").append("div")
            .attr("id", "container")
            .style("width", width + "px")
            .style("height", height + "px");

    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
            .center([-73.94, 40.70])
            .scale(80000)
            .translate([(width) / 2, (height)/2]);

    var path = d3.geo.path()
            .projection(projection);

    d3.json("nyc.json", function(error, nyb) {

    var map = container.append("svg")
            .attr("id", "boroughs")
            .style("width", width + "px")
            .style("height", height + "px");

    var chor = d3.scale.quantile()
        // I don't want to manually specify the domain. How can I get the extent of a property from my shapefile?
        .domain(d3.extent(nyb, function(d) { return d.properties.someno; }))
        // manually specifying the domain works:
        //.domain([0,100])
        .range(["#f8eb60", "#f6bd5a", "#f09253", "#ec654a"]);

    map.selectAll("path")
            .data(nyb.features)
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", function(d){ return d.properties.borough; })
            .attr("d", path)
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
          return chor(d.properties.someno);
        });

        legendheader = d3.select("#legendcontainer")
            .append("p")
            .append("text")
            .text("Legend")
            .style("font-size", "16px");

            var leg = d3.select("#legendcontainer").append("svg");
            var legend = leg.selectAll('g.legendEntry')
            .data(chor.range())
            .enter()
            .append('g').attr('class', 'legendEntry');

            legend
                .append('rect')
                .attr("x", 10)
                .attr("y", function(d, i) {
                   return (i * 20) + 5;
                })
               .attr("width", 15)
               .attr("height", 15)
               .style("stroke", "none")
               .attr("fill", function(d){ return d; });

            legend
               .append('text')
               .attr("x", 35)
               .attr("y", function(d, i) {
                  return (i * 20) + 5;
               })
               .attr("dy", "0.8em")
               .text(function(d,i) {
                   var extent = chor.invertExtent(d);
                   return +extent[0] + " - " + +extent[1];
               })
               .style("font-size", "14px");

    });

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're passing the wrong thing to `d3.extent`.

Should be the `features`-array not the whole `nyb` object:

```
d3.extent(nyb.features, function(d) { return d.properties.someno; })
```

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. Thanks so much!